# How do I query for all items which have a specific item embeded in doctrine odm

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-odm, doctrine-query

I have Comments for something and it's possible to like them. The likes are saved in the `Comments` as `EmbedMany(targetDocument=User)`.

I want to query for all `Comments` a Specific User has liked, how do I do that?

I thought of something like:

```
$dm->createQueryBuilder('Comment')
    ->field('likes.id')
    ->in(array($user->getId()))
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query on the embeded document as if it were a normal field. It's type is an ObjectId, though, so you have to manually create the MongoId to query on.

```
$dm->createQueryBuilder('Comment')
    ->field('likes.$id')->equals(new \MongoId($user->getId()))
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

and just to note, for references it would be:

```
$dm->createQueryBuilder('Comment')
    ->field('likes')->references($user)
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```